# How to change the text of an Label tag when a checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, label, innerhtml

I can't change the text of my label when I unchecked my checkbox.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
var checkBox_fruit = document.getElementById("fruit");
var label_fruit = document.getElementById("label_fruits");

checkBox_fruit.addEventListener('change', function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        // Checkbox is checked..

        label_fruit.innerHTML = " fruits 1"; ////// its that who works

      } else {
        // Checkbox is not checked..

        label_fruit.innerHTML = " fruits 2"; ////// its that who not works

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, you just forget to add closing bracket `});`.

See the demo.

```js
var checkBox_fruit = document.getElementById("fruit");
var label_fruit = document.getElementById("label_fruits");

checkBox_fruit.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    // Checkbox is checked..

    label_fruit.innerHTML = " fruits 1"; ////// its that who works

  } else {
    // Checkbox is not checked..

    label_fruit.innerHTML = " fruits 2"; ////// its that who not works

  }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="fruit" />
<label id="label_fruits"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only needs some closing `})` at the end.

```js
 var checkBox_fruit = document.getElementById("fruit");
 var label_fruit = document.getElementById("label_fruits");

 checkBox_fruit.addEventListener('change', function () {
      if (this.checked) {
          // Checkbox is checked..
         label_fruit.innerHTML = " fruits 1"; ////// its that who works
      } else {
          // Checkbox is not checked..
         label_fruit.innerHTML = " fruits 2"; ////// its that who not works
      }
 });
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' id='fruit'>
<label id='label_fruits'>Fruit</label>
```